# How to install Rose compiler on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, c, unix, compiler-construction, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to Linux. I have been asked to install rose compiler. I installed the dependency Boost by using

```
apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

which installed boost1.58.0 but now when I use

```
apt-cache search rose
```

I cant understand which package is for the rose compiler from the list provided. I downloaded rose from the github repository https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose but I cant understand how to install it.

Comment: http://rosecompiler.org/ROSE_HTML_Reference/installation.html

Comment: I installed boost1.58.0 by using ''apt-get install libboost-all-dev''. Then what is my boost installation directory?

Answer (score 1):

The ROSE installation process is a mangled mess. If you can, use their [pre-built image](http://www.rosecompiler.org/Ubuntu-ROSE-Demo-V3.tar.gz). If you can't, I'd recommend running [this shell script](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose-develop/blob/master/scripts/2017-03-ROSE-Unbuntu-16.04-VM-setup.sh) instead. Note that the part with downloading Java does not work, so **before running the script** download **JDK 7u51** from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) and leave it in the Downloads folder (do not move or rename!) for the script to pick up. This was working as of ~1 month ago (July 2017). No guarantees if it still works.

Also note that the installation process takes a lot of time. The entire ~2 million line project needs to be compiled on your machine. After installation, don't even think about moving any of its folders or dependencies. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 or CenOS/RHEL 7 then you can install rose using apt/yum. https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose/wiki/How-to-Set-Up-ROSE has all the information regarding this.